# Copy matching cells based on one column

Tags: vba, excel, indexing, vlookup

Please see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lGDW8IoH-29kGbwYrtuyCb51f_tAZSUDpCKIXxwgA5I/pubhtml?gid=82101138&single=true) for snippet from my spreadsheet, what I am trying to do is fairly simple, however I am unable to find a way to do this after searching through online forums extensively.

Column A contains my order numbers and column B the line items that correspond to each order number.

Column D contains the delivery date as it appears on my printed order sheet, you will see this only pulls through for the first line item on each order - the raw data displays this way and so there is way to change the raw data

Column E simply extrapolates just the date rather than the format Delivery Date: dd/mm/yyyy.

What I would like then, is for column E to have the delivery date copied down to all corresponding cells for each order number - so as per the attached sheet, 30 Jul 2015 would appear for all line items that correspond to order no #1192.

I feel v look up etc will only work to manipulate data once I have these dates copied down. I have tried index match but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to do.

Is there a way to copy down the dates for all line items relative to their order number? I understand that it will probably require copying full lines down column D first and keeping the formula in column E to extrapolate just the date.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: i would create macro to check if row(n) and row(n+1) in A column is equals,  if so i would set row(n+1) in E column text to data from row(n). thats what you want yes?

Comment: I think a macro would be an overkill here. Also, if the table is huge, the loop could be slow.

Comment: Why didn't `Index` and `Match` work for you? If you use `=INDEX(A:E;MATCH(A3;A:A;0);5)` in cell `E3` of you sheet, doesn't it return `30 July, 2015`? That, with @vacip answer should do the trick.

Comment: Would you be happy using col E as a "helper" and have the result in col F?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a macro for this. There are many ways to go about this, I'll show you two, you can figure out the one you like from there.

Select coloumn E, go to **Home**, **Editing**, **Find & Select**, **Go To Special**. Hit **Formulas** (if the values are not formulas, go for Constants), and check only **Errors**. Now type **=E2** (or whatever is above your active cell), and hit **Ctrl+Enter**. It is a wise idea to copy-paste values the whole coloumn E after this.

Another way would be entering this formula in coloumn F (cell F2, then pull it down):

```
=IFERROR(E2;F1)
```

Or you could combine this with your original formula, or use a macro to insert the formula in the empty/#error cells etc...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `=RIGHT(D2,LEN(D2)-FIND(":",D2)-1)` in E2, then you are well on the way to a solution.

You also mentioned INDEX/MATCH which, if used in column F will pull the Delivery Date in Column E for each Order No:

`=INDEX($E$2:$E$31,MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$31,0))`

This finds the position of the first match for your Order No and returns the Delivery Date from column E.